# Error with a .gz file decompression in Mint, but works perfectly in Windows, so the file is not corrupt

Tags: compression, gzip

I've downloaded some `.csv` files from the OECD Stats website, since I need them to plot some graphs with `gnuplot`. When I open them with File Roller 3.4.1 (the default program to handle archive files), there's a file that seems empty (0 byte). When I try on the terminal, I get:

```
gunzip Financial\ Indicators\ –\ Stocks.gz

gzip: Financial Indicators – Stocks.gz: invalid compressed data--length error
gzip: Financial Indicators – Stocks.gz has more than one entry -- unchanged
```

So the file seems corrupted, but I sent it to a friend who uses Windows. He extracted the file on his computer and sent me the output: it's a zip files which, in turn, contains two `.csv` files. So the file is not corrupt, there must be a problem with the packages used to handle them. Any suggestion?

Comment: Run `file Financial\ Indicators\ –\ Stocks.gz`, to see what's actually there.

Comment: The output is: Financial Indicators – Stocks.gz: Zip archive data, at least v3.0 to extract

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a zip then the file extension is wrong, and you can not use `gunzip`. If it contains 2 files then it is not a gzip file, `gunzip` works with single files, it just compresses, sometimes we use it with tar to combine file. It may be zip or tarred zip `.taz`

Use file command to find out.

If zip
You need `unzip`.

Also if zip change the file extension, as some tools may use this to detect file type.

Comment: The output of file is: Financial Indicators – Stocks.gz: Zip archive data, at least v3.0 to extract

Now I'll try with unzip

Comment: Solved with your answer. Just needed to change its extension to .zip.

Comment: Write an angry mail to OECD to make them correct the file extension.